# add custom loss to eval_metric_ops

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml-engine

I have defined my own loss function using [sequence_loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/sequence_loss)

```
loss = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, labels, weights)
```

I am hoping to add this to eval_metric_ops so that in my ML engine package I can display the evaluation loss in tensorboard continuously (defaults are just accuracy).I tried adding this as a custom eval_metric_ops

```
eval_metric_ops = {
    'loss': loss # this has already been coputed for Modes.EVAL
}
```

However, I get the error "TypeError: Values of eval_metric_ops must be (metric_value, update_op) tuples, given: Tensor("sequence_loss/truediv:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) for key: loss" -- what do I need to do to pass the loss as an eval_metric_op? I guessing that my current loss should be the metric value, but I'm not sure what the update_op should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metric function in your case can be implemented using `tf.metrics` using an moving average of the loss:

```
def metric_fn(labels, predict):
   loss = tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.sequence_loss(logits, labels, weights)
   mean, op = tf.metrics.mean(loss)
   return mean, op
```

Comment: I believe the [`tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_mean) function does this automatically. Though, it's in contrib so users beware.

Comment: @EliBixby isn't that function the same as `tf.metrics.mean`? i haven't checked the source but it has the same parameters and returns.